# Solving for probability in equation involving Beta function

Tags: probability, beta-function

Consider the equation
$$p^\alpha(1-p)^\beta = cB(\alpha+1,\beta+1)$$
where $c,\alpha,\beta>0$ and $B(\alpha,\beta)$ is the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

**Question:** What is the probability $p$ as a function of $c,\alpha,\beta$?

Comment: The Beta function in this equation is irrelevant. You simply want the inverse of the function $p^\alpha(1-p)^\beta$ which I believe can only be found for specific values of $\alpha,\beta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As  @Peter Foreman commented, you only need to find the zero of function
$$f(p)=p^\alpha(1-p)^\beta-k$$ and, for the most general case, you will need some numerical method.

From a practical point of view, I think that it would be better to consider
$$g(p)=\alpha \log(p)+\beta \log(1-p)-\log(k)$$ Its derivatives
$$g'(p)=\frac{\alpha }{p}-\frac{\beta }{1-p}\qquad \text{and} \qquad g''(p)=-\frac{\alpha }{p^2}-\frac{\beta }{(1-p)^2} <0 \,\,\, \forall p$$ The first derivative cancels at
$$p_*=\frac{\alpha }{\alpha +\beta }$$ which corresponds to a maximum (by the second derivative test. So, if 
$$g\left(\frac{\alpha }{\alpha +\beta }\right)=\alpha  \log \left(\frac{\alpha }{\alpha +\beta }\right)+\beta  \log
   \left(\frac{\beta }{\alpha +\beta }\right)-\log (k)$$ is positive, there will be roots to the equation. One root will be $0 < p_1 <\frac{\alpha }{\alpha +\beta }$ and the second one $\frac{\alpha }{\alpha +\beta }< p_2 <1$.

Start the search at the midpoint of the interval and use Newton method.

For example, let us use $\alpha=10$, $\beta=17$ and $c=\frac 1 {15}$. For the first root, the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & p_n \\
 0 & 0.185185 \\
 1 & 0.238691 \\
 2 & 0.258600 \\
 3 & 0.261070 \\
 4 & 0.261105
\end{array}
\right)$$ and, for the second root,
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & p_n \\
 0 & 0.685185 \\
 1 & 0.561947 \\
 2 & 0.503743 \\
 3 & 0.490163 \\
 4 & 0.489394 \\
 5 & 0.489392
\end{array}
\right)$$